# Number of m letter pairs with a vowel in the alphabet

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The number of ways to choose m unique pairs of letters from the alphabet is:
$$
\frac{26!}{(26-2m)! m! 2^m}
$$

Which gives 325 single pairs, 44850 double pairs, 3453450 triple pairs...

If I want to add the following constraint: *"at least one letter in each pair must be a vowel"*, how many m-pairs can be generated then?

Comment: i am a little curious shouldn't it be $$\frac {26!}{(26-2m)!(2m)!}$$

Comment: @user146269 no, the number of possible pairs is $C(26,2)*C(24,2)*C(22,2)*...$, which is $26! /((26-2m)! 2^m)$, divided by the number of ways of permuting the $m$ pairs, which is $m!$

Comment: yeah i just realize that sorry about that

Comment: In your above calculation, it seems like you're not letting any doubling of letters between two pairs; is that your intention?  That is, do you allow for ab, ac to be a valid double pair?

Comment: @MarcusM Yes, that is intentional. ab-ac should not be valid. I meant m-pairs of unique letters instead of unique pairs in my description, my bad.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe there's an elegant way to do this.  It's just going to be a whole bunch of brute-force cases.

Comment: @MarcusM I already implemented a brute force method which computes the ouput pretty much instantly. That's the simplest way to program it anyway since 26! doesn't fit in standard 64 bit types. I was just curious about the arithmetic behind it.